# TFS Build definitions copy repository to UNC

Tags: tfs

I want to make a build definitios in TFS 2015 that copies all files in a repository to a given UNC.

This is not a VS project, but a set of web files that all are compiled.

Any ideas how this can be solved?

Comment: There is a task named 'Copy Files', can you use that ? Just create an empty definition that only contains this task

Comment: No, don't have the 'Copy Files' task

Comment: Which version of tfs2015 are you using ? tfs2015 update3 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a PowerShell for the job.

```
#
# Deploy.ps1
#

param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$targetPath
)

Function Deploy-Package() {
    Copy-Item "$Env:BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY\*" $targetPath -Recurse
}

Deploy-Package

Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Deployment successful"
```

Answer (score 0):

[Copy Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/utility/copy-files) task exists in TFS 2015.3 and newer versions. You could upgrade your TFS 2015 to the latest edition TFS 2015.4 and use this task.

Otherwise, you could use [Copy and Publish Build Artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/utility/copy-and-publish-build-artifacts) task, which is available since TFS 2015 RTM.